# How to capture net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED globally in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I have a web Application built using react and payment gateway is stripe, My application occasionally throws "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" , I need to capture this error and display to the user, Kindly assist me on this.

Comment: That means you sent a xhr request to a domain name that your computer could not resolve (find the IP)

Comment: We have many ways to do that. You need to be more specific.

Comment: In my React webapp, When ever I receive net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED usually happens when slow internet bandwidth occurs , I need to capture that in my app.js and show my own custom msg to the user ,